# With MVC 2 I want to fire action every 10 seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a view called DataProgress and when it is shown in my browser, I want it to re-fire the same action that produced it every 10 seconds. My action is DataProgress in the controller MyController.

I tried the following, but it seems to fire the method ever few seconds (not 10 seconds) and in the browser I do not see anything shown at all.

```
<script>
  $(document).everyTime(10000, function () {
    <% Html.Action("DataProgress");%>;
  }, 100);
</script>
```

JD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<% Html.Action("DataProgress");%> does nothing but to render the action ONCE when the view is executed and to insert the result into the place where you placed the Action command.

In other words: Html.Action is a server-side command, it cannot be called by javascript code.

What you need to do is to use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or similar jQuery methods (load and getJson might also work depending on your needs) and update your page accordingly.

Comment: Hi Adrian, what I want is the whole page to be fetched, so the action that generated the page must be called again from within itself (I remember seeing a meta tag in HTML that just reloaded the page, which I what I want). Can I do this by firing an action (rather than updating a portion of the page with ajax)?

Comment: @JD: $.ajax() always executes (in your words: fires) a server-side action from the client side. What you do (or not do) with the result is irrelevant. So yes, you can do this. In this case you probably want to use $.get or $.post depending on your action method. $.ajax would also work fine, but it's a bit more verbose.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. That worked perfectly. I had my partial view in the wrong folder which did not help but switching to an ajax call works perfectly.